# Gnu time and formatting output

Tags: linux, gnu

I wanted to use gnu time to measure running time of some little .c programs. In the man it is written that:

```
-f FORMAT, --format FORMAT
Use FORMAT as the format string that controls the output of time.  See the below more information.
```

Then in examples we have:

```
To run the command `ls -Fs' and show just the user, system, and total time:
time -f "%E real,%U user,%S sys" ls -Fs
```

But when I try to issue this command from example i get:

```
time -f '%E real,%U user,%S sys' ls -Fs
-f: command not found

real    0m0.134s
user    0m0.084s
sys     0m0.044s
```

I am wondering where is the problem, where am I making a mistake? I just want to show the user time, that is why I am toying with time output format.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bash for one has a shell builtin named `time`. One way to get past it is to type `command time` - command will ignore the builtins and run the `time` program from your `$PATH`. Another way is `alias time=/usr/bin/time`. On the other hand the bash builtin respects environment variable `TIMEFORMAT`.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I will just use TIMEFORMAT, but all of those work.

Comment: `/usr/bin/time` isn't available on some systems (e.g. NixOS), but I've found that `command time ...` works as a way to avoid the bash builtin.

Comment: Great point, `command` is a POSIX-defined shell utility so it ought to be available in `sh` and in anything (including `bash` and `ksh`) that can act as `sh`. As was mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365795/invoking-program-when-a-bash-function-has-the-same-name

Answer (score 1):

The documentation also mentions `env time` to use the `time` command from the system (it uses `/usr/bin/env` or alike, so it should be independent of the shell).