# Time command's illegal option

Tags: macos, shell, time, gnu

I am having some issues with the time command `time`. It works fine but since time gives 3 numbers in output(real, user and sys) I was looking on how to get only the user time. 
I found many posts that say to use `/usr/bin/time -f "%U"` but I get this errors :

```
/usr/bin/time: illegal option -- f
usage: time [-lp] command.
```

I also can't find the option `-f` when I type `man time`

I tried to skip it and write:`/usr/bin/time "%U"` and I get `%U: No such file or directory`

I have installed GNU-time but nothing changed. what is the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gnu time and formatting output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715570/gnu-time-and-formatting-output)

Comment: Are you on OSX?

Comment: @DanFromGermany I am on macOS

Comment: [The `-f` option is totally fine](https://www.gnu.org/software/time/), you are accessing the wrong binary. The `time` you installed, must be somewhere else located on your computer. Click the link, it shows how to find out which `time` you are using (`type time`).

Comment: then why does `man time` only shows `-l` or `-p` as options?

Comment: If you installed `gnu-time` with **homebrew**, you need to use `gtime` or `/usr/local/bin/gtime` if you didn't set your PATH.

Comment: @MarkSetchell gtime worked. thank you!

Comment: Wow, nice information Mark, this `g` prefix is new to me, too. I have added `gnu` and `macos` tags to the question. The situation is different on generic linux systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several `time` commands...

---

If you run:

```
type time
```

and get:

```
time is a shell keyword
```

that means you are using `bash`'s built-in shell command that does not accept the option you want. The `help` for this command, like all shell built-ins, is available using:

```
help time
```

---

If you run:

```
type time
```

and get:

```
time is hashed (/usr/bin/time)
```

that means you are using the Apple-supplied (BSD-like) `time` command that does not accept the option you want. That is also the one described in the man-pages.

---

If you installed `gnu-time` with **homebrew**, you need to run:

```
gtime
```

unless you didn't set your `PATH` to include `/usr/local/bin` like you should if you use **homebrew**, in which case you would need to run:

```
/usr/local/bin/gtime
```

and view the man-page with:

```
man gtime
```

If you want to always use the command `time` in place of `gtime`, and I would not recommend this, you need to run:

```
brew info gnu-time
```

and read what it says about setting:

> PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-time/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"