# How to tell bash to specifically escape a wildcard in a Python script

Tags: python, bash, shell, wildcard

I have a script. It takes arguments, but I would like it, when it receives the string "`*`", to autocomplete it to a matching string in a list variable.

Unfortunately, this is impossible without the user escaping the wildcard using a backslash to escape the asterisk:

```
foo.py ba\*  # Will expand to "bar"
```

Not doing so would result in bash expanding it to a file in the working directory, then passing it to my script.

What is required to tell bash to not automatically expand the asterisk and just pass it to my script. Maybe an install script?

Comment: try `foo.py 'ba\*'` ie. use single-quotes

Comment: Ideally I would like to have this not require quotes and not globally set autocomplete off. Examples: `apt-get install gnome-*`, `yum install gnome-*`, etc.

Comment: What you're asking can't be done. You have to either use quotes or disable globbing. However, what you can do is to put your code in a function or a script. A script cannot make changes globally!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. How could I 'put ... [my] code in a ... script'?

Answer (score 5):

```
set -o noglob
```

will prevent bash from expanding the `*`.

Remove with `set +o noglob`

Comment: +1 Also spelled `set -f` for those trying to reduce wear-and-tear on their keyboards, but this version makes it clearer what feature is being disabled.

Comment: see my (now added) comment.

Comment: @zheoffec - eh, what comment?

Comment: On the question (i added it some time after - as i anticipated your response would not be so fast ;))

Answer (score 3):

Simply call it like so to escape in bash:

```
foo.py 'ba*'
```

Comment: It's basic functionality of bash.  As far as I know, you will have to live with it, or turn off globbing (see Fredrik Pihl's answer).