# how to convert 1,000,000 gifs into a video file using ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

i have 1 million gifs in a folder that i would like to convert into a 60 frames per second video file using ffmpeg. Here is my code:

```
ffmpeg -r 60 -pattern_type glob -i *.gif -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```

my gifs don't follow a %07d.gif pattern like 0000001.gif 0000002.gif but they are indeed in sequential order. like this: img1.gif, img2.gif ... img10.gif ... img10000.gif ... img1000000.gif.

When i try to execute my code i get this:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: Argument list too long
```

please help. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to avoid the pattern being expanded by your command shell, and instead pass it to the program as is. This can be achieved with quotes.

The man page has this example

```
 ffmpeg -r 10 -f image2 -i 'img-%03d.jpeg' out.avi
```

So in your case, you could try

```
 ffmpeg -r 60 -i '%07d.gif' -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```

Comment: Try `img%d.gif` then.

Comment: still doesn't like it - img%d.gif: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

The shell is performing file name expansion on the given commandline, namely `*.gif`.
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion) on how to prevent it using quotes.

Also, the sequence pattern type looks more useful in your case. Something like the following should work:

```
ffmpeg -r 60 -pattern_type sequence -i "img%d.gif" -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```

If I understand correctly, the problem with globbing is that it will sort your file in alphabetical order i.e. img-1.gif, img10.gif, ..., img2.gif, img20.gif...