# Passing glob results through to a function discarding all but first file

Tags: bash

I have the following function `f() { find . -name "$1"}` which is just a handy shortcut for finding the file with a name. If I execute `find . -name "*.gradle"` in the terminal I get:

```
./.gradle
./app/build.gradle
./build.gradle
./dependencies.gradle
./settings.gradle
./wearable/build.gradle
```

If I execute `f *.gradle` in the terminal I get:

```
./app/build.gradle
./build.gradle
./wearable/build.gradle
```

The first result is the correct one and also the wanted one. Why am I getting though this 'wrong' result when using my function even though the content is the same? Did I inject the `$1` parameter wrongly?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Maybe you mean `f() { find . -name "$1"; }`, or your real code has a newline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f *.gradle
```

expands the glob, replacing `*.gradle` with a list of files in the current directory, which then may run something like the following:

```
$ f one.gradle two.gradle
#   $1         $2
```

which then runs:

```
find . -name one.gradle
```

...passing only the first file (`$1`), and ignoring all others.

---

If you want to pass the glob through to find:

```
f '*.gradle'
```

Comment: Is it possible to make `f *.gradle` work without using the `'`?

Comment: No. (There are explicit questions on that topic already in the knowledge base, btw).

Comment: @Niklas, ...see, for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion

Answer (score 4):

You need to use quotes to prevent the expansion beforehand in the current shell and let the expansion take place within the function:

```
f '*.gradle'
```

Comment: Is it possible to make `f *.gradle` work without using the `'`?

Comment: @Niklas Then you need to use `$@` to indicate all positional parameters inside `f` (not just the first one): `f () { find . -name "$@" ;}`

Comment: @heemayl, that wouldn't actually work here -- you'd need to construct `-name "$1" -o -name "$2"`, etc., and even then, it would only include files whose names matched glob targets in the current directory, not in children.