# Prevent wildecard expansion with system() function call

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell, wildcard-expansion

I have read this: [Stop shell wildcard character expansion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion) and similar - this is *not* a duplicate question.

I am dealing with a set of legacy c++ code, from which a number of binaries are built.  This code uses `system` function to execute a shell script passing it some arguments.  Unfortunately, as it turned out, some arguments may include `*` character, yet arguments are not properly escaped.  As a result, when the shell script is execute, the `*` gets expanded, which is not what I want.  Here's a simple code to replicate the issue:

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$i => $var"
    ((i++))
done
```

**program.cpp**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::string command = "/tmp/sh/script.sh *";
   return system(command.c_str());
}
```

When the compiled binary executes, I get the list of files as parameters to the shell, instead of the asterisk:

```
$ ./program
1 => program
2 => program.cpp
3 => script.sh
```

Now, if I turn off glob expansion in shell using `set -f` or `set -o noglob`, then calling the script directly works as expected:

```
$ set -f
$ ./script.sh *
1 => *
```

However when the script is executed with `system`, this doesn't work:

```
$ set -f
$ ./program
1 => program
2 => program.cpp
3 => script.sh
```

Is there any way to prevent the expansion when command is executed via `system`?

I really want to avoid having to rebuild the binaries, as operationally and managerially it would be an enormous amount of work.

**UPDATE:** As I mentioned, I want to **avoid any changes to the cpp source**; I want to simply disable glob expansion on the OS level (via any flags, changed files, etc. - I'm happy to modify any files on the box if needed).

Comment: You can shadow library `system()`  function with your own.

Comment: Doesn't the shell let you execute two commands on the same line?

Comment: use `"set -f; script.sh *"` or call `set -f` inside the script?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès The first would require changing cpp source and rebuilding; the second isn't going to work, because expansion happens before the script executes.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I'm not sure what you mean. Yes, it does, but which two commands and where?

Comment: @Slava That would require changing the source and rebuilding the executables

Comment: @AleksG no that does not require changing source, only relinking. You can avoid relinking as well if you can inject shared lib.

Comment: Then search if shell launched from `system()` uses any `.profile` startup file.

Comment: @Slava Ok, fair point, only relinking - but I would have to go through a release process of the new binaries, which is an enormous amount of work.

Comment: You can create a shared lib with your own `system()` function and add it by LD_PRELOAD var

Comment: Consider *not* using `system()` at all. You don't know what shell or environment you'll get and it's quite prone to security issues (for example; it inherits your processes permissions). A solution with `fork()` + one of the calls from the `exec*()` family​ offers far more control and safety.

Comment: @JesperJuhl You seem to miss the main question: how to do it **without** changes to the application. The source code is several megabytes (millions of lines); there are multiple branches for different versions; `system` is used a hundred of times in the code.

Comment: @Aleks G. I did see that. But sometimes it's worth it to refactor a bunch of code to arrive at a better solution going forward. :-)

Comment: LD_PRELOAD definitely seems like the way to go. You might also be able to extract the original command from `/proc/<shellpid>/cmdline`, and since you're willing to modify system files, you can replace `/bin/sh` with a wrapper

Comment: @Slava After some investigation, I got LD_PRELOAD trick to work.  Post that as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Just post whatever you did with enough code to reproduce it, that'll be more helpful to future readers than merely our suggested directions ^^

Comment: @Slava I ended up using LD_PRELOAD - and it worked quite well.  If you post that as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of closing the loop, as Slava didn't post the answer... Copied from his comment:

> You can create a shared lib with your own `system()` function and add it by `LD_PRELOAD` var

I ended up using this method - and it worked perfectly fine.