# "set -f" in bash not working

Tags: bash, macos, glob, wildcard-expansion

Related: [Stop shell wildcard character expansion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion)

I had in the past used `set -f` in bash to prevent glob expansion - however this seems to not work on my mac any more:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo $0

i=1
for var in $@
do
    echo "$i => $var"
    ((i++))
done

$ set -f
$ ./script.sh *
./script.sh
1 => program
2 => program.cpp
3 => script.sh
```

With the `set -f` I expected the output to be

```
$ ./script.sh *
./script.sh
1 => *
```

What am I missing and how can I stop the expansion.

Comment: Quote `$@`, `set -f` is only valid for the current shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the script in a separate shell (running `./script.sh` forks a sub-shell) than the one you actually set the option `set -f` on. Try putting it inside the script so it runs with the option set,

```
$ ./script.sh *
./script.sh
1 => *
```

Or you can source the script in the current shell as below with the `set` option applied.

```
$ set -f
$ source script.sh *
/usr/bin/bash
1 => *
```

See this cross-site reference [What is the difference between executing a Bash script vs sourcing it?](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it) which provides some nice insight into the problem we are dealing here.

Comment: D'oh! sometimes I just need another pair of eyes (and/or more sleep).

Comment: @AleksG: Happens all the time ;)