# Programming with ASCII conversions in a calculator program

Tags: c

I need some help with my simple calculator program. It seems to work fine until I use the `*` symbol for multiplication. When I use the `*` symbol it comes out to be `99` instead of the ASCII equivalent of `42`. The arguments it expects are an integer, operator(`+` ,`-`, `*`, `/`) and another integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*
void usage() {
    printf("This is a calculator program, just put in to numbers and and operator\n");
    printf("Example:\n\t2 + 2\n");

}
*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int first_number, second_number;
    int symbol;
    int sum;

    first_number = atoi(argv[1]);
    second_number = atoi(argv[3]);
    symbol = (int)*argv[2];


    printf("symbol varable = %d\n", symbol); // debugging for argv[2]

    if (symbol == 43 ) {

        sum = first_number + second_number;

        printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
    }

    else if (symbol == 45 ) {

        sum = first_number - second_number;

        printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
    }

    else if (symbol == 42) {

        sum = first_number * second_number;

        printf("sum = %d\n", sum);

    }
     else if (symbol == 47) {

        sum = first_number / second_number;

        printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's cool that you are learning how to code, but I think you should also learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just a tip: Using explicit characters instead of trying to use ASCII values (`'+'` instead of `43`) makes the code more readable and portable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem or question you're asking. The title should be useful to a future reader who sees it in a list of search results. *Please help me with my calculator* is absolutely meaningless, *having some issues* is simply useless noise, *(C language)* is apparent from the tag, and you can show your appreciation by upvoting or accepting (or both) answers that help you instead of saying it in the title. Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is that you have a program (possibly called `calculator`) in your directory, and when you run `./calculator 9 * 23`, the `*` is expanded by the shell so your program is passed `./calculator 9 calculator calculator.c 23` or something similar, and your code sees the `c` and finds code `99`.  To run the program accurately, use `./calculator 9 '*' 23` (or `./calculator 9 \* 23`, or `./calculator 9 "*" 23`).  Basic debugging technique: print your inputs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with your code.

When you run your program with command line parameters like `12 * 12` you are putting a wildcard in the command line and the shell sees the `*` and replaces it with a list of every filename in the directory - The first program in the directory must start with a lower case c if the symbol comes out with 99.

To make it work escape your command line parameters like `12 '*' 12` or `12 \* 12` or disable filename globbing altogether as shown in this answer: [Stop shell wildcard character expansion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion)

Comment: So the program isn't called `a.out` because then the `*` would be expanded to a name that begins with `a` (`97`) instead of `c` (`99`).  I agree with the rest of your diagnosis.  I'd also recommend `printf("[%s] [%s] [%s]\n", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);` to diagnose the problem.  The code should also check `if (argc < 4)` before using the arguments.

Comment: I used a.out because he didn't say what it was called and that's the default.  But you're right - it must be called calc or calculator or something in order for the first file to start with c.  I should change it so it makes more sense but it will only be really helpful if I guess the name of the executable correctly...

Comment: See my comment to the main question for how I'd do it.