# How to pass "*" argument to main()?

Tags: c, shell

I wrote a program that can accepts arguments from the command line, which are supposed to be a number, an operator (of length 1) and another number:

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[]){
    if (argc < 4){
        printf("Too few arguments (4 required)");
        return -1;
    }

    char *a = argv[1];
    char b = *argv[2];
    char *c = argv[3];

    printf("%s %c %s = ...", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Which seems to work fine, such as when I pass `110 + 11` I get:

```
110 + 11 = ...
```

But if I pass something with the operator `*`, like `110 * 11`, it messes up:

```
110 b c_nums.cbp = ...
```

The only thing that seems to work is if I replace `*` with `^*` or `'*'` and change `char b = *argv[2];` to `char b = *(argv[2]+1);`

I'm assuming this has to do with how cmd or whatever formats commands, but how can I fix this without always passing `^<op>` instead of `<op>`?

Edit: Ok, so it looks like `"*"` works in cmd but *not* Code::Blocks for some reason.

Comment: this is because the shell will expand the * to a list of files. You need to quote the * when you run the program

Comment: If four arguments are required, change expression to: `(argc != 4)`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion

Comment: This has nothing to do with C, it is the shell which you are calling your program from.    You could also use `\*`

Comment: `"*"` gives me a similar outcome to `*`, as does `\*`

Comment: The quotes are stripped by the shell before the program is called.

Comment: Have you considered using `x` to indicate multiplication?

Comment: you actually solved it yourself by using '*' - ie quoting the *

Comment: i would suggest passing the calcuation as a single string - ie `myprog '12 * 34 - 42'

Comment: Is this *Windows*?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The Windows command prompt doesn't have special treatment for `*`.  Globbing is done by individual commands.

Comment: Yes but is this something like some MinGW startup routine or sometihng?

Answer (score 1):

The `*` character has special meaning to the shell.  It gets interpreted before your program is even executed.

You need to escape the `*` from the shell in order for your program to see it, either by preceeding it with a backslash or enclosing it in quotes.

Comment: Good catch.  A wildcard.