# Python: glob only returns one result on path pattern

Tags: python, glob

Pythoncode:

```py
for name in glob.glob(first_argument):
    print(name)
```

Bash:

```sh
>$ ls
> a.txt b.txt c.txt program.py
>$ ./program.py *.txt
> a.txt
```

Somehow glob recognises the pattern, but will only find one match.
However, If i write:

```sh
>$ ./program.py "*.txt"
> a.txt
> b.txt
> c.txt
```

I dont get it. Try to find answers in documentation, but couldnt manage. Anyone knows why? Thanks

Comment: In the first case, the shell expands the wildcard and passes all 4 files to your code. In other words, length of `sys.argv` is 4. When you use `first_argument`, you are effectively `glob`ing `a.txt` and hence, the result. However, shell expansion does not occur in the second case and `*.txt` is passed as-is, which is then handled by `glob`.

Answer (score 2):

when you run `./program.py *.txt` in bash, it automatically expands `*.txt` to `a.txt b.txt c.txt program.py`

You then pass them all to your program and run the glob only on the first param `a.txt`

When you add the `"` around it you actually pass `*.txt` as the argument to glob

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how to prevent bash from interfering with the arguments given. I want the program to get exaclty what user wrote without the "

Comment: @Snusifer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion