# How to set multiple argument with postgress helm 3.0

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to set `slave.extraVolumes` as below.

```
helm install my-db --set replication.enabled=true,slave.extraVolumes={"db-disk-1","db-disk-2"} bitnami/postgresql -n development
```

But it says a error

```
Error: expected at most two arguments, unexpected arguments: bitnami/postgresql
```

Already tested ways:

```
helm install my-db --set replication.enabled=true,slave.extraVolumes={db-disk-1,db-disk-2} bitnami/postgresql -n development
Error: expected at most two arguments, unexpected arguments: bitnami/postgresql

helm install my-db --set replication.enabled=true,slave.extraVolumes="db-disk-1\,db-disk-2" bitnami/postgresql -n development
Error: YAML parse error on postgresql/templates/statefulset-slaves.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 115: could not find expected ':'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are (at least) three things going on:

- the [`slave.extraVolumes` is a **list** of `Volume` structures](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/postgresql/templates/statefulset-slaves.yaml#L271-L273), so just providing two names won't get it done
- you are using characters that are meaningful to the shell without quoting them
- but in the end it doesn't matter because you cannot represent complex structures using only `--set` syntax, you'll need `--values` with either a file or a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution)

```shell
helm install my-db \
   --set replication.enabled=true \
   --values <(echo '{
      "slave": {
        "extraVolumes": [
          {
            "name": "db-disk-1",
            "emptyDir": {}
          },
          {
            "name": "db-disk-2",
            "emptyDir": {}
          }
        ]
      }
   }') \
   bitnami/postgresql -n development
```

Answer (score 2):

For others who come from Google with the error message and want to solve that, rather than the obscure `postgresql`-specific answer in the accepted answer, the problem is almost certainly mdaniel's point 2 ("you are using characters that are meaningful to the shell without quoting them"), at least for modern `bash`.

This answer explains what is going on - [Stop shell wildcard character expansion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion) - and how to fix it. Here you need to escape just the curly brackets, so something like:

```
helm install my-db --set replication.enabled=true,slave.extraVolumes='{"db-disk-1","db-disk-2"}' bitnami/postgresql -n development
```

or

```
helm install my-db --set replication.enabled=true,slave.extraVolumes=\{"db-disk-1","db-disk-2"\} bitnami/postgresql -n development
```

Is what you need. The `helm` help is annoyingly silent on this.

Comment: Tried escaping curly brackets with both ' and \  and this is working.