# Click with Path type behave differently once imported

Tags: python, import, path, click

Let's imagine I have a simple Python script `do_stuff.py` who list subfolders in a given folder:

```
import click

@click.command(help="Do stuff.")
@click.argument('datasets', type=click.Path(exists=True, readable=True, writable=True), nargs=-1)
def main(datasets):
    for dataset in datasets:
        print(dataset)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In my case it returns the expected list of folder when I run `python3 do_stuff.py ./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/*`:

```
./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220121
./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220206
./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220222
./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220310
```

When I try to do the same thing from another script `master.py`, importing `do_stuff.py`:

```
from do_stuff import main as ds

ds('./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/*')
```

When I run `python3 master.py` it returns:

```
Usage: master.py [OPTIONS] [DATASETS]...
Try 'master.py --help' for help.

Error: Invalid value for '[DATASETS]...': Path '/' is not writable.
```

If I modify the last line of `master.py` into `ds(['./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/*'])`, then I get:

```
Usage: master.py [OPTIONS] [DATASETS]...
Try 'master.py --help' for help.

Error: Invalid value for '[DATASETS]...': Path './s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/*' does not exist.
```

Thanks in advance for any help you could provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to fully understand the behavior that looks different that you misattributed as "Click with Path type behavior differently once imported", may I recommend the following experiment.  In your `do_stuff.py`, check what arguments `click` actually received when from the command line `'./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/*'` was passed.  This may be done by adding these couple lines before `main()`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    print(sys.argv)
    main()
```

Now run it:

```
$ python do_stuff.py ./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/*
['do_stuff.py', './s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220121', './s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220206', './s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220222', './s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220310']
./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220121
./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220206
./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220222
./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220310
```

Note how it's actually a list of the four files that you have, and the `*` is nowhere to be seen inside the program.  This is because from the shell, it [automatically expands the wildcard character before the command is actually run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion), so Python (thus `click`) will only see the fully qualified filenames and the loop runs happily.

A easy way to emulate the failure from the command line (without having to muck about with `set glob` as per the linked thread in the previous paragraph) to repeat the failure you saw from calling `ds('./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/*')` is to pass in a path with a wildcard that will not be resolved to any file, example:

```
$ python do_stuff.py /tmp/a_dir_does_not_exist/*
Usage: do_stuff.py [OPTIONS] [DATASETS]...
Try 'do_stuff.py --help' for help.

Error: Invalid value for '[DATASETS]...': Path '/tmp/a_dir_does_not_exist/*' does not exist.
```

Since the shell cannot expand that wildcard argument, its unmodifed form is passed as an argument to the program, and in the example it emulates calling `ds(['/tmp/a_dir_does_not_exist/*'])` as per the failed example in the question.

Now, if you want to use the same glob syntax from within Python, you may use the [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) function to replicate the automatic wildcard expansion in the shell, example:

```
>>> from do_stuff import main as ds
>>> from glob import glob
>>> ds(glob('./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/*'))
./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220310
./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220222
./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220206
./s3_data/lsc2/landsat_ot_c2_l2/LC08_L2SP_195027_20220121
```