on macos, git clean <pattern> not working recurcively (like unix)
Under linux, I used to use git clean *.orig, or git clean *.orig *.swp *.swo to clean my repositories while keeping some untracked file.
For example, with the following repo status:
$ git status
composer.json.orig
config/services.yaml.orig

The command git clean *.orig remove composer.json.orig, then if I execute git clean *.orig again, the file config/services.yaml.orig is removed.
However, I now have to work on mac os, and the command doesn't work the same, the subdirectories are not cleaned.
How can I make this works like under unix ?

What about git clean **/*.orig?

@evolutionxbox good idea ! but only subdirectories are cleaned, not in . . (I thought I already tried it but I didn't in fact)

No difference in git, but in the way you use it. In the first command, your wildcard expands to a single file name. Since git sees only this name, it can only deal with this file. In the second invocation, the argument is not expanded, and git sees *.orig and cleans all matching files. You can protect yourself against this type of mistake by putting into your .zshrc a setopt bad_pattern. This would have produced an error message in the second git command, from which you could have concluded what‘s goint wrong.

Unix/Linux shells expand unescaped/unquoted metacharacters like *. When you have files that match wildcard template *.orig in the current directory the shell expands the template to a list of files and pass the list to the command so instead of git clean *.orig the shell executes git clean composer.json.orig. After the file is removed in the next command git clean *.orig the shell doesn't expand *.orig because there are no files in the current directory that match the template so it really executes git clean *.orig and Git expands the template recursively.
There are two ways to work around that. First, instead of using simple template *.orig you can use *.orig **/*.orig to make the shell expand the template in the current directory and recursively so the shell executes the command git clean composer.json.orig config/services.yaml.orig.
The second way is forbid the shell to expand the template at all and make it pass the template unchanged/unexpanded to Git so Git works recursively on it. For this either escape the asterisk with a backslash: git clean \*.orig or use single/double quotes: git clean "*.orig". Shells don't expand asterisk templates inside quotes. (The difference between single and double quotes is that shells don't expand anything inside apostrophes/single quotes but expand $environment_variables in double quotes).
The bottom line is: remember when the shell expands metacharacters and when you want to protect them from expanding.

Thanks for the solution (I just found 5 minutes ago that "*.orig" works and was going to answer myself), and even more thanks for the explanation ! Do you know if there is a way to avoid using ?
(I will mark it as «accepted» answer later, just in case where someone has a way to make it works without quotes or escaping)

@Asenar https://stackoverflow.com/a/11456496/7976758 set -o noglob Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshell%5D+disable+asterisk+expansion

@Asenar https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/580984 In zsh there is noglob prefix. Found in https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=zsh+disable+asterisk+globbing

@phd noglob is often used with an alias, e.g. alias gc='noglob git clean'.

thanks you very much @Gairfowl and @phd ! I will probably make alias git='noglob git' so ! (and this is likely the answer that solves my problem!)
